# Angular 2 web application within an already existing Maven project

Tags: node.js, eclipse, maven, angular, npm

In order to present a brand new way of developing a web application, our team decided to create an Angular 2 web application that will be integrated within an already existing Maven Project in Eclipse Mars which DOES NOT use NodeJS nor Angular.

We are currently using the `frontend-maven-plugin` belonging to `com.github.eirslet` and managed to download and install both node.exe and npm.
Now, here is the deal: our web application has its own `package.json` file with all the configuration required to run properly, BUT we would like to be able to differentiate between the web applications, as each one of them belongs to a different working directory (i.e. `com.webapp.app01`, `com.webapp.app02`, ...).

As the plugin does not let the user use the `npm install` command on different directories, we were wondering about how we could reach this goal... maybe using a general `package.json`, but generating all .js and dependency files in each project directories.

Would that be something even possible?
Could you give us some help?

Thank you.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We decided to generate all the libraries locally and upload them to SVN, due to the fact that the already existing structure cannot be changed and the maven plugin is too much limited for our purpose.
Thank you for your replies, though. :-)

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is to have a multi-module maven project, with a common parent, and children, that would give you this kind of architecture:

```
parent-project
|-child-project1 (java project)
|-child-project2 (webapp1)
|-child-project3 (webapp2)
|....
|-child-projectn (webapp n-1)
```

This way you can have for each web-app the frontend plugin available. And you can handle the flow of the build from the parent project (for instance if webapp2 needs to be built before webapp1, you can orchestrate it from the parent)

Comment: Unfortunately, we cannot apply what you suggested. Even though it is a good solution, we are forced to integrate the new web application pages and typescript files into the already existing java project we have. We managed to download and install NodeJs through Maven, but we should be able to generate all the files and dependecies within the java project and only for the Angular projects as well.

Comment: Then you could use my above diagram and promote the java project as the parent and let each child execute npm with the frontend plugin or is it excluded as well ?